# Is there some Error class replacement for PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-5.4

I like to use the PHP **Error** class to return using throw like this:

```
throw new Error('Some problem description');
```

Sadly, I have to use **PHP 5.4.16** on CentOS 7.5. The Error class was introduced in PHP 7.

Is there a class that I can include which emulates the behavior of the Error class from PHP 7?

Comment: the classic alternative is `throw new Exception('message);` or even `trigger_error()` maybe?

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes, this is a good replacement. But I thought that there maybe already exists some class that emulates the Error class from PHP 7? So I can write the code for PHP 7 but stay compatible with old PHP 5.4.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php#error.synopsis) and [Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php#flash-message) have the same exact signature so you can possibly use the latter:

```
if (!class_exists('Error')) {
   class Error extends Exception
   {
   }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JqGgE)

Tweak for you liking. For instance, you may want to [check PHP version](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php#example-588) (it's possible that software written for PHP/5 already has a custom `Error` class). Of course, no native function is going to actually throw it.

Comment: Thanks! This weas the sort of replacement I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Error` class in PHP 5, but this class is the same as the `Exception` class. If you want to generate custom errors then use `Exception`

```
throw new Exception('Some problem description');
```

There is no difference between `Error` and `Exception` class from a functional point of view. The only reason why we have the two is for semantic purposes. We don't want PHP 5 code after upgrade to PHP 7 to catch Fatal errors using `try() catch(Exception $e)` logic.